# Where does SAML get additional PF value from

Tags: http, cookies, single-sign-on, saml

I'm trying to automate the download of a report that is secured using SAML.  I'm walking through the steps used when the document is accessed from a browser (Firefox).  I can trace the flow of information except for the appearance of a third PF value.  The third PF value first appears in a Request header (it never appears in a response header or in the body of any of the responses prior to this).  The request occurs after a 401 response is received making a request with the PF value returned in a 200 response to a request made using the PF value that is returned in a response header.

Answer (score 1):

That's not SAML, that PF cookie is set by PingFederate, which is your Identity Provider (IdP). See: https://support.pingidentity.com/s/global-search/%40uri#q=PF%20Cookie&sort=relevancy for how frequently it's mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, but where does the third PF number come from (the one ending in XwxK in this example)?

Comment: It's a cookie that Ping sets every time you interact with them.

Comment: It's not set as a Cookie: The PF number never appears in a response header.  Somehow Firefox magically adds it as a request header.  Where does the magic happen?  What causes the second request to be issued by Firefox (the request after the 401 response that returns the 200 response)?  Javascript is disabled and there is no resource in the body of the response that would cause a request to be issued that I can see.